# jQuery triggering action on page load

Tags: jquery

I currently have the following code to add a lightbox to links that have `rel="facebox"`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox();
});
```

This works well until a page takes a little too long to load.

How do I apply this before the document has loaded? Ideally I'd like to call the `.facebox()` function first and as the DOM loads, it searches for any link with `rel="facebox"` and applies the function.

Kind of like the `.on()` function but without an event.

Does that make sense? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't call it before the DOM is ready, that selector won't match anything then!

Comment: @tymeJV You can place the JS directly after the HTML element and it'll be selectable before the `document.ready` event fires. This is a fairly common practice to speed-up rendering of JS heavy sites. You'll likely want to use native JS rather than a framework like jQuery because then you won't have to wait for jQuery to load...

Comment: you can delay the page load with setInterval(). So you can run your function first, then display the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my solution by doing the following:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[rel*=facebox]', function() { 
    $.facebox({ ajax: $(this).attr('href') }); 
    return false; 
});
```

Hope that helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of links here that might help out with this issue...

[Working with elements before the DOM is ready](http://blog.keithclark.co.uk/working-with-elements-before-the-dom-is-ready/) and [Detect DOM Node Insertions with JavaScript...](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-node-insertion)